# why getRefCount is not incremented?

Tags: python, python-internals, reference-counting

`L` is initialized to a list. Then add reference a `L1` to `L`. Now both the `L1` and `L` variables should point to same object. So why does `sys.getrefcount()` still return 1?

```
>>> L = [1,2,3]
>>> L1 = [1,2,3]
>>> L==L1
True
>>> L is L1
False
>>> sys.getrefcount([1,2,3])
1
>>> L1 = L
>>> L1 is L
True
>>> sys.getrefcount([1,2,3])
1
```

Comment: Because you are testing the reference count of a **new** list, created in the expression to produce the argument for `sys.getrefcount()`.

Comment: When L1 is L returns true, L1 is also reference to [1,2,3]. Or is it L1 is a reference for L alone and not [1,2,3]?

Comment: That's the wrong question. `L` and `L1` never reference the new list object that the `[1,2,3]` syntax produces when you execute `sys.getrefcount([1,2,3])`. Each time Python executes `[1,2,3]`, a new list object is created.

Comment: Why would you think that a programming language would intern representations of a complex *mutable* data structure?

Comment: @JaredSmith: I don't see any evidence that the OP is even thinking of interning here. You could start with *Where you thinking of interning here*? first? We know next to nothing about their experience level or mental model of object storage behaviours.

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair, if OP new what interning is then the question would likely not have been asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating *new* lists. Each new list has just a single referrant, the reference held by the argument to the `sys.getrefcount()` function.

If you want to see the reference count for the list objects that the `L` and `L1` names reference, then you'll have to pass *those names* into the `sys.getrefcount()` function:

```
>>> import sys
>>> L = [1,2,3]
>>> sys.getrefcount(L)
2
>>> L1 = L
>>> L1 is L
True
>>> sys.getrefcount(L)
3
>>> sys.getrefcount(L1)
3
```

`L` starts with 2 references: the `L` name itself, and the argument to `sys.getrefcount()`. When you then also assign the object to `L1`, there is now one more reference to it.

Don't get confused between the syntax that produces the list *value*, and what is stored in memory. If you imagine having two *identical* shopping bags, and you go to the store and put a packet of cookies in one bag, and another packet of cookies from the same type in the other bag, are the two bags the same thing? They *look* the same, you could eat those cookies and they'd *taste* the same, but they are still *two separate bags with cookies in them*. If someone stole one of those bags you'd still have the other bag to eat the remainder of the cookies.

Writing `[1, 2, 3]` in Python tells Python to make a *new* shopping bag (list) and put in some cookies (integer numbers). That new bag looks the same as the other bags (lists), so they have the same *value* (`==` returns `True`), but they are not the same single bag (`is` does not return `True`).

Now, put post-it notes on those bags, giving the bags names. Write `L` on one note, stick it on one bag. Write `L1` on the other note, stick it on the other bag. Their values are still the same, but when you ask Python if `L` and `L1` are the same bag, then you know they are not, the post-it notes are stuck to two different bags. But what if you were to move that `L` post-it note from the one bag it was stuck to, and move it to the other bag that has `L1` stuck to it? Now you have two post-it notes on the same bag, so `L is L1` is true now.

`sys.getrefcount()` tells you how many post-it notes there are stuck to the bags. But you need to tell it about post-it notes, not new bags.

And finally, you can put those bags inside other bags, or put the bags inside [labeled drawers in a filing system](https://roarsweetly.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/img_1206-2.jpg) (or `dict` objects), and `getrefcount()` would count those too. Because post-it notes are not the only way to track shopping bags, right?

Comment: Thank you MarijnPieters for taking time and explaining it.

Comment: I actually started with a question that, Is there a way to getrefcount of object "cookies in the bag". As per python memory optimizations same object is reused whenever possible. Looks intern has some info, i will read about that. thanks again, pl bear with me. I am just starting out with python programming language. python-internals is far off.

Comment: @Guru: Python can't just re-use already created objects everywhere. There are some that are re-used (small integers, tuple objects are recycled, some strings are interned), but that's all CPython implementation specific. Do search here on Stack Overflow, I have written several answers under the `python-internals` tag that talk about such optimisations.